# Date format years-months in R

Tags: r

I have a data in the following format 200101 and I want it to be in the following format 2001-01 or 2001/01

Thanks

Comment: You are getting down votes because you do not show us what you have tried so far and where exactly you get stuck. There are links to possible solutions popping up while you type the question!

Comment: I need to ask another question but i can't since people have rated my questions as -ve

Comment: how Can I increase my Rate so I can ask questions?

Comment: @MarwahSoliman - to [up your reputation] (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast), and always research if your question has already been asked before you ask it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't deal with dates so there may well be better approaches.  Your problem is you have no day.  I know the zoo package can handle this but not in the format you want.  I also give a regex approach but this is not a date class, just character.

**As date**:

```
library(zoo) 
as.yearmon("200101", "%Y%m") 

## > as.yearmon("200101", "%Y%m") 
## [1] "Jan 2001"
```

**As character:**

```
gsub("([0-9]{4})","\\1-", "200101")

## > gsub("([0-9]{4})","\\1-", "200101")
## [1] "2001-01"

## gsub("([0-9]{4})","\\1/", "200101")
```

Comment: Now I want to plot the data such that I get 2001-01 and so on.

I tried PCP <- ts(pcp, frequency = 12, start = 2001) plot (PCP)

but it only gives the years.

Thanks

Comment: I see you have a new question to address this.  Please link this response to that one and if this question has been answered you can mark it as so and provide a bit more data there so it's [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can I ask you a question Tyler?

Comment: I need to ask one more question what shall I do and my rates are low?

Comment: I would ask a new question and highlight the corner case if there is one.

Comment: @ TylerRinker-I can't ask a new question because my rates are low so what should I do in this case?

Comment: You can as rates have nothing to do with the ability to ask a question.  I see you keep getting downvoted and closed because you haven't read the [posting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and are asking poorly formed questions.

Comment: Well when I press ask a question I get the following message"Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account".

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: I don't know how to improve my questions I found them logic ones, maybe my English isn't perfect but I'm trying to ask good questions can I have your email I would like to ask one last question?